# How to set a class path in java for jexcelapi

Tags: java

I installed java and set path, its running successfully. Now i need is how to make use of  jexcelapi. I download jexcel api and extracted it. I dono where to place the extracted file and also I dono how to set CLASSPATH for jexcel file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the CLASSPATH variable, because it's global to all the Java programs.

Use the `-classpath` (or `-cp`) option when running java. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html for details.

Answer (score 0):

You basically only need to put the jxl.jar file in the classpath of your program. To make it easier, you can just make sure that file is in the same folder that you run your program from. It needs to be in the build path of your program, so if you use eclipse you can just add the jxl.jar file to your build path.

In eclipse, it runs things from the target or bin folder usually, so you would need to make sure the file was in that folder if you wanted to run it from the command line.

The key is just having jxl.jar by your .class file or .jar depending on how you execute your program.